# How to give color to chart

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to make a chart with color like below:

But, this is my first time to make a chart, I only know to give a single color, like mine below:

Here I attach the code of my chart:

```
                          child: SfCartesianChart(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            legend: Legend(
                              position: LegendPosition.top,
                              isVisible: true,
                              textStyle: body1(),
                            ),
                            tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
                            primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
                              labelStyle: body2(),
                            ),
                            primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(labelStyle: body2()),
                            series: <ChartSeries<dynamic, dynamic>>[
                              SplineAreaSeries<ChartData, String>(
                                color: ColorName.brandPrimaryBlue,
                                dataSource: chartData,
                                xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.data,
                                yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) =>
                                    data.totalItem,
                                name: 'Item',
                                markerSettings: const MarkerSettings(
                                  isVisible: false,
                                  color: ColorName.brandPrimaryBlue,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: I will keep in mind, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use gradient property of SplineAreaSeries like this:

```
SplineAreaSeries<SalesData, String>(
                            gradient: const LinearGradient(
                              colors: <Color>[
                                Color.fromARGB(80, 9, 59, 167),
                                Color(0xFF012168),
                              ],
                              stops: <double>[0.2, 0.7],
                              begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              end: Alignment.topCenter,
                            ),
                            dataSource: <SalesData>[
                              SalesData('Jan', 35),
                              SalesData('Feb', 28),
                              SalesData('Mar', 34),
                              SalesData('Apr', 32),
                              SalesData('May', 40)
                            ],
                            xValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) =>
                                sales.year,
                            yValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) =>
                                sales.sales,
                            // Enable data label
                            dataLabelSettings:
                                DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true),
                            markerSettings: const MarkerSettings(
                              isVisible: false,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          )
```

which will give you results like this:

[image]

which you can customize by chagning the colors values etc according to your choice.